# Getting confused why i dont get expected amount?

Tags: math, billing, mathematical-optimization

I have 1 result and which i will receive in Bank account, Based on that account i have to Put a balance to user account.

How can you find the Handling cost from total tried 491.50 / 0.95 =  517.36 which is wrong ? It should be 500.00 (to my expectation)

User balance requires 500.00
When 500.00 selected he gets 5% discount
There is a handling cost for this

```
ex:
1) Discount: 500.00 - 5% = 475.00    
2) Handling cost: (475.00 x 0.034) + 0.35 = 16.50   
3) Total: 475.00 + 16.50 = 491.50
```

So problem is from 491.50, i have to find atleast handling cost to get promised Balance.

Any solution ? Cant figure it out myself...

In short cut:
a) i put 491.50 -> b) my formula will suggest me apply balance 500.00 (which is the main goal)

Comment: Is this a programming question? What language are you using? Where's the code that performs this way?

Comment: Yes it is a programming question, but same as explained above. If it has to be a code here it is where the 491.50 gets generated. ex: https://gist.github.com/752386

Comment: What is your question? 491.5 / 0.95 does equal 517.368. Can you define things? What is Balance, Handling Cost...

Comment: Forget about the code... I didn't understand a single sentence in this question.

Comment: What are the known figures from which you need to get the 16.50? You cannot get 16.50 from just knowing 491.50 and 5% discount, but you can if you also know the original cost was 500.

Comment: 491.5 - 500 * .95 = 16.50, hence you need all three figures on the LHS as I said.

Comment: My problem is i dont know 500.00 (which i want to know from 491.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(final_price - 0.35) / 1.034 / 0.95

For 491.50, this yields 500.

You might try to combine the last 2 divisions to be divide by 1.034 * 0.95 = 0.9823, but you will have to guard against rounding errors due to using floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

So, your maths can be represented as:

`((0.95 * initialCost * 0.034) + 0.35) + (0.95 * initialCost ) = finalCost`

which reduces to

`(0.9823 * initialCost) + 0.35 = finalCost`

It follows that

`initialCost = (finalCost - 0.35) / 0.9823`

Comment: thanks, last one works, but did you get 0.9823 was not clear, i later find out that 1.034 * 0.95 need to be apply, but already i had 0.35 and 1.034 as variable. so i applied (final_price - 0.35)/ 1.034 / 0.95 = my result